# Best migration tools to migrate the content from Sitecore 8.2 to Sitecore9 Update 1

Tags: content-migration

Please let me know if any tools exist in market place to migrate the content from Sitecore 8.2 to Sitecore 9 Update 1.
Need to automate this job for 40 site nodes.

Existing 8.2 solution is legacy one. 
Redesigned the solution using Helix principles and Sitecore9
All templates and Items restructured.

Comment: You don't need to use the express migration tool if you are on Sitecore 8.2. 

Did you check this article? https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/5/t/8659

Comment: Hari, are you just upgrading from 8.2 to 9 or is this completely new development on 9, and want to migrate content from old version? Reason for this question, if is re-written, i would assume, there would be templates restructure, then i am afraid Migration tool will not help you..

Comment: We have developed the solution using Helix principles and Sitecore9. So I have to migrate the content from 8.2 old instance to new 9.1 instance.
Consider it as new development in 9 and want to migrate content from old instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Sitecore Express Migration Tool 3.1 makes it easy for customers to help migrate Sitecore 6.6,7.2, 7.5 or 8.0 to the latest version of Sitecore Experience Platform 9.0 without the need to gradually upgrade from version to version.

The Express Migration Tool Migrates:

- Content items and media
- All users, roles and security permissions
- Assists with configuration migrations

To update you solution to 9.0.1 you need to update manually from 9.0 initial release.

More information you can find at: https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Express_Migration_Tool/31/Express_Migration_Tool_31.aspx

**UPDATE**

Like @Jay S said :  On the updating [guide](https://dev.sitecore.net/~/media/EF33CB99BD4D4EBBA40B9E67AFDB5344.ashx) is described how you can update your solution using updating packages starting from version 8.1

Comment: Thank you for your reply but we didnt upgrade the instance from 8.2 to 9.
Need to migrate only content to 9 Instance from 8.2 instance.

Comment: why do you want to migrate just the content ?

Comment: We have developed the solution using Helix principles and Sitecore9.  So I have to migrate the content from 8.2 old instance to new 9.1 instance.

Comment: on 8.2 solution did you follow Helix rules when you structure your items,renderings,templates,etc?

Comment: In 8.2 the solution not using Helix principles. Its legacy application

Comment: As a note, the migration tool is not the best way to upgrade from 8.2, as it is meant for 8.0 and under. From 8.1 forward, you can use the update packages